# Qt 4.8.4 (i386/x64) on Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt4

Is there way to keep both x64/x86 packages for qt 4.8.4 on one linux machine?

For example, when I'm trying to install qt4 bin package:

`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev-bin:i386`

I only get warning:

`The following packages will be REMOVED: libqt4-dev-bin`

The same thing for qt4-qmake and other qt4 packages.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, but you have to download them by hand from the qt website and save them in separate locations, then if you use qt creator, you can use the qt versions tab to add them to the available project targets as per https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: I think there is only source version of qt libraries on official website for qt 4.8.x.